# String HTML is not compiling using angular $compile having scope variables in it

Tags: angularjs, angular-directive

I have a html string which uses the ngrepeat to render the required div..

```
var templateHTML = "<div ng-repeat='entity in createCtrl.finalCCList'>\
                             <span>{{entity.name}}</span>\
                         </div>";
```

Here "createCtrl.finalCCList" has list of entity object which has name and id properties in it. Now when I try to compile this using -

```
 var compiledTemplateHTML = $compile(templateHTML)($scope);
 if (compiledTemplateHTML && compiledTemplateHTML[0]) {
    return compiledTemplateHTML[0].outerHTML;
 } else {
    return "";
 }
```

I get nothing. Whereas i checked and $scope.createCtrl.finalCCList does have the required values.

Am I missing anything here.

Comment: You're using properly the service by doing `$compile(templateHTML)($scope);`. Could you post the entire idea of what you're trying to do in order to see if there is any other problem somewhere else. I mean, post how you're bind the info in the html, etc.

Comment: why don't you use `ng-bind-html`

Comment: @sachilaranawaka  I need the html in string format in order to pass to one of the data-attr for jqyery plugin I am using to render that

Comment: Be aware that the `ng-repeat` directive builds DOM asynchronously *after* the function enclosing the $compile returns. The $compile returns a jqLite element with a comment node on which the `ng-repeat` will later build DOM.